# How to Remove the SearchView blue line in Android

Tags: android, searchview

Can anyone help me to remove this or change it to another color ?

[This Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGJeW.jpg)

Thank You so much for your help

Comment: The `SearchView` is used in a `Toolbar`?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20085725/searchview-remove-blue-focus-line-and-show-cursor-at-certain-postion/20556187#20556187

Comment: No,  I make that using SearchView .

Comment: @sasikumar Thank you for that . But what if I use Hexadecimal codes in color . How to put that ?

Comment: This solution seems promising. Please give it a try. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30843200/1987045

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your SearchView in xml, if using API 21 or higher. If using an API lower than 21. use `android` instead of `app`.

```
app:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: Only in API 21 and higher. For lower you should use `app:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"`. Check the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38663324/1101730

Comment: Just check that link one more time.

Comment: Yeah sorry, it's the other way round ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
View v = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_plate);
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("here give color code for background"));
```

Comment: Usually it is a good idea to add an explanation on what your code does. This allows newer developers to understand how the coed works.

Answer (score 2):

u can use

```
View searchplate = (View)mSearchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_plate);
            searchplate.getBackground().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.another_color) ,PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```